# How to calculate the flow of air that leaks out of a container?

Tags: pressure, temperature, gas, volume

I cannot grasp what should be a simple gas problem (last time I worked with gas formulas was 40 years ago). Values I provide here are just for the sake of explanation.

There is a thermically isolated container of volume V=1m³.
It contains compressed air with pressure P=5bar and T=300K.

I make a hole on a side of the container (area A=1mm²) and the air spills out to environment (Te=290K).
The pressure P inside the container of course decreases (no idea about what happens to T).

**My question:** In a ideal system is measuring P and T along the time enough to determine the air leak flow, or are there other parameters I should take into account?

As an extra curiosity, is it possible to calculate the temperature of the leaking air as soon as it leaves the hole?

I tried working with the Ideal Gas Law (it looks the most promising formula) but as the number of moles n changes I don't know what to do with it.

[What is the temperature of compress air entering the atmosphere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251322/what-is-the-temperature-of-compress-air-entering-the-atmosphere) seems promising but I don't really understand how to apply the law of adiabatic expansion in my case. Wikipedia is definitely above my reach...

Comment: One term to search on is "choked flow"...

Comment: What you are describing is a [Joule expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion).

Comment: @JohnRennie, as I understand Joule expansion the gas spreads into a second container, so the number of moles is kept the same. In my case the gas (compressed air) is going to open air. I don't see how the two can be considered the same phenomenon.

Comment: @AlexPoca No, a Joule expansion can also be into an infinite vacuum.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I need to find an easier explanation because up to now I don't understand how it can be the same system when Volume is infinite and number of moles change.